# Paypal Express Checkout API vs PayPal button for Websites

Tags: security, button, paypal

What is the difference between PayPal button for Websites and the Express Checkout API? Why would one use the API rather than the button? What additional functionality/ other advantages does it provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Website Payments Standard, uses HTML buttons that you create from within your account whereas Express Checkout will use API calls to complete the payment.  You will also have more control over the checkout flow as well with Express Checkout, since the buyer will be back on your site when they complete the payment.  You can calculate shipping and taxes, on your site.  You can split the payment up between different accounts using Express Checkout Parallel payments where you can not  with Website Payments Standard.

Most merchants like the fact that you have more control over the checkout flow than you do with Website Payments Standard buttons.  For example, you could direct the buyer to the credit card section specifically on the checkout page, or you could send them to the PayPal login section.  With Website Payments Standard, you can not do this.  It relies on cookies, and you can not control this with standard.